# Django forms.ModelForm - placeholder not showing

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform

I've the following code in my `forms.py`:

```
class CandidateSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('__all__')
    widgets = {
        'first_name': forms.TextInput(
            attrs = {
                'placeholder':'Ime',
                'class': 'validate'
            },
        ),

        'last_name': forms.TextInput(
            attrs = {
                'placeholder': _('Prezime'),
                'class': 'validate'
            },
        ),

        'email': forms.EmailInput(
            attrs = {
                'placeholder': _('E-mail'),
                'class': 'validate'
            },
        ),

        'password': forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs = {
                'placeholder': _('Lozinka'),
                'class': 'validate'
            },
        ),

    }
```

Part in templates is simply `{{ form.first_name }}`. Now, placeholder doesn't work for `first_name` and `last_name` form fields, but does for `email` form field. Would someone please share some info on what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already specified the fields in the class itself, you should be using inline widgets (since the `Meta` widgets field is for overriding default widgets).

```
class CandidateSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Ime', 'class': 'validate'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Prezime'), 'class': 'validate'}))

    class Meta:
        ...
```

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields